# Please anyone tell me how i solve this problem.please help someone

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

Notice (8): Use of undefined constant ankitgir_deshbhakt - assumed 'ankitgir_deshbhakt' [CORE/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php, line 69]

````
Code Context
        include_once APP . 'Config' . DS . 'database.php';
        if (class_exists('DATABASE_CONFIG')) {
            static::$config = new DATABASE_CONFIG();
```
````

```
ConnectionManager::_init() - CORE/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php, line 69
ConnectionManager::getDataSource() - CORE/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php, line 83
Model::setDataSource() - CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 3626
Model::setSource() - CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 1155
Model::getDataSource() - CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 3653
Model::_readDataSource() - CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 3031
Model::find() - CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php, line 3003
Video::getDetails() - APP/Model/Video.php, line 75
ConfigController::view() - APP/Controller/ConfigController.php, line 53
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 491
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 193
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 167
require - APP/webroot/index.php, line 110
[main] - ROOT/index.php, line 41
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, CakePHP thinks that the database table named `video` is missing. What have you done to debug this problem? Is the table actually missing in the database? Do you maybe expect the model to use a different table? You need to provide a little more context here as to what exactly the problem is here that you cannot / don't know how to solve.

Comment: but video is avaiable in the database .i want to tell you full story. i uploaded database file in my phpmyAdmin. then it is giving error so someone install cakephp i don't know how he upload.but that problem is solved.now it is giving error of " Table video for model Video was not found in datasource default." when i see in phpmyadmin, video  is there. many time i try to solve this problem by internet but everytime i am unable to solve. someone told me that use mysqli at the place of mysql.i don't know anything about cakephp so please help

Answer (score 1):

If a table exists in a database and cakephp says there is no such table in default datasources then you may have misspelled or even forget to put database name in config file, check if database name is correct in configuration.